# C++ - Converting input to "*" and converting back to letters from a file

Tags: c++, passwords

As many people might of come across this problem when creating a bank account program, passwords are annoying, having to convert them to `*` and then back again to letters to check if they are correct. That is my exactly my problem. Has anyone come across this problem, and how did you fix it. If you're looking for me to say about research, I've looked in nearly every c++ forum and absolutely found nothing on converting back from `*` to letters, but the opposite way around. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Passwords aren't *converted*, they're just displayed as things like • in the field. Whatever are you trying to do here?

Comment: @tadman I think I know how to make the input into `*` but not back to chars again.

Comment: @BramwellSimpson Didn't you read the duplicate? You do not "make the input into `*`" - you store the input as normal, but print `*` instead of echoing the input.

Comment: Once you change something to `*` there is no going back. Remember **display** and **storage** are two different things.